# How to return from IBAction into root Split View Controller into Master View Controller

Tags: ios, swift

I am having an issue with returning into root Split View Controller. I have a login page with a button on a separate View Controller and I want the user to return to Split View Controller after they login. The code that I have returns the user into root Split View Controller, however it takes him into empty Detail View controller. What change do I need to implement so the user is taken into Master View Controller with data?

```
 @IBAction func goHome(sender: AnyObject) {
 let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
 let splitViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SplitViewControllerID") as! UISplitViewController
 let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
  appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = splitViewController    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement this method from UISplitViewControllerDelegate protocol:

```
  func splitViewController(_ splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondary secondaryViewController: UIViewController, onto primaryViewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    return true
  }
```

When this method returns true, your master view controller will be shown by default.